# What is the best way to access this data?

Tags: c++, vector

For a program that I am working on, I am getting data from mysql and writing to a csv file.  Then I am going to take the data from the csv and put it into a 2d vector in C++.

It is likely that my csv file will be on the scale of anywhere between 1 and 1.5 million rows, and 8 columns.  Now the csv can be thought of as a bunch of chunks sorted by an ID number.  That is, for example, maybe the first 100 rows belong to ID number 1, the next 80 rows belong to ID number 2, and so on.  The reason I put them all in one csv is because requesting data from mysql is slow and I only want to make one request.

My question is, would it be better in my C++ program to create one large vector (1.5 million x 8 ) containing the entire csv file at once, or do a loop where I am creating a 100 x 8 vector, then an 80 x 8 vector, and so on?  I am sorry if I have not formulated this question well. If you have any other questions to help clarify I would be glad to answer.

Comment: The first question is, do you need all the data at once? Can you stream the data to be analyzed? The first thing i would do is code it any way that I think will work. If it turns out to be too slow then rework it wtih the new requirements. Never make up requirements you don't know you will need.

Comment: A list (maybe a linked list) might work faster if you are going to make modifications to such a big amount of data

Comment: It looks you don't need all data once , keep some records(2d vector) ex :1000,write into csv file .

Comment: Can you not do the sorting in `SQL` and leave the *vector* out altogether?

Comment: "1.5 million x 8" what? `double`, `int`, `std::string`, a combination?  Anyway, your database probably has a utility to dump the data to CSV, and you can google for C++ libraries that parse/load CSV data.  It's off-topic on Stack Overflow to seek library recommendations.  If the data's simple (e.g. no quoted/escaped strings), and you're inclined, you can hack up some parsing quite simply and there're lots of existing answers about that.

Answer (score 0):

Theoreticaly allocating big chunk will be better(new has better perfromance on big chunks). If you are using `std::vector<T>`, don't forget to reserve enough memory from the start, in order to prevent reallocation when you will fill it with data.

Comment: As RedX comments under the question, ***if*** it's possible to allocate a small chunk (e.g. a few hundred to store the rows with the same ID number, even at the risk of having to dynamically grow that a few times), that's generally better than a big chunk and loading the whole file (reusing the same memory for successive parts of the file reduces peak memory use and potential consequences - cache misses, swapping, out-of-memory conditions).

Answer (score 0):

First of all decide do you prefer to do look up later depends on the ID, you can use a `std::unordered_multimap` where key as your record ID and other elements are the member variables of your class.Two dimensional array will be not effective as `std::unordered_multimap` here and impossible to use ID as key for look up because you will fail to convert index of `vector` as your ID, since there are repetitions of IDs.

If you prefer look up create a structure or class to keep all other elements of record as data members of the class and use ID as key  of an `std::unordered_multimap`. This is the case of you are available with C++11.

If you don't have C++11, and if you prefer multi key look up, prefer to use `std::multimap`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research on std::unordered_multimap.  I never even heard of it.

Comment: @nonremovable please note it is an available data structure in C++11